# Front end posting

Tags: front-end, wp-insert-post, wp-redirect

This source works with image upload. Without image upload, it works, but 'redirect' doesn't work. What should I do?? Any suggestions to what the problem might be?

```
    if( 'POST' == $_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] && !empty( $_POST['action'] ) &&  $_POST['action'] == "new_post") {

    // Do some minor form validation to make sure there is content
    if (isset ($_POST['post_title'])) {
        $title =  $_POST['post_title'];
    } else {
        echo 'Please enter a game  title';
    }
    if (isset ($_POST['description'])) {
        $description = $_POST['description'];
    } else {
        echo 'Please enter the content';
    }

    $new_post = array(
        'post_title'    => $title,
        'post_content'  => $description,
        'post_status'   => 'publish',
        'post_type' => 'property',  
        'tax_input' => array( 'property_type' => array($property_type), 'suburbs' => array($suburbs) ) 
    );


    //save the new post and return its ID
    $pid = wp_insert_post($new_post);
    update_post_meta($new_post_id, 'tax_input', $property_type);
    update_post_meta($new_post_id, 'tax_input', $suburbs);

    //insert custom fields
    update_post_meta($pid,'property_lease',$_POST['property_lease']); 
    update_post_meta($pid,'lost_found_date',$_POST['lost_found_date']);
    update_post_meta($pid,'dog_sex',$_POST['dog_sex']);
    update_post_meta($pid,'address',$_POST['address']);
    update_post_meta($pid,'price',$_POST['price']); 


       //add thumbnail
        if (!function_exists('wp_generate_attachment_metadata')){
                require_once(ABSPATH . "wp-admin" . '/includes/image.php');
                require_once(ABSPATH . "wp-admin" . '/includes/file.php');
                require_once(ABSPATH . "wp-admin" . '/includes/media.php');
            }
             if ($_FILES) {
                foreach ($_FILES as $file => $array) {
                    if ($_FILES[$file]['error'] !== UPLOAD_ERR_OK) {
                        return "upload error : " . $_FILES[$file]['error'];
                    }
                    $attach_id = media_handle_upload( $file, $pid );
                }   
            }
             if ($attach_id > 0){
    $post = get_post($pid,'ARRAY_A');
    $image = wp_get_attachment_image_src( $attach_id );
    $image_tag = '<img src="'.$image[0].'" width="'.$image[1].'" height="'.$image[2].'" />';

    //add image above the content
    update_post_meta($pid,'_thumbnail_id',$attach_id);

    //add image under the content
    //$post['post_content'] = $post['post_content'] . $image_tag;    
    }


    $url = get_permalink( $pid );
    wp_redirect($url);
    exit();
}
```

Comment: Do you have [debugging information](http://codex.wordpress.org/Debugging_in_WordPress)?

Comment: Jim in your code are you sending an array of suburbs to a custom taxonomy? I'm having trouble with similar code getting a comma separated list from an input to insert correctly. How are you sending / collecting a list of suburbs on your front end? Thanks

Answer (score 1):

You can not use `wp_redirect()` if the headers have already been sent so snippet you provided **should not be used within your template files**, instead you should wrap it within a function and place it into your functions.php file and hook onto `template_redirect` action.

Example:

```
add_action('template_redirect', 'front_end_post', 99);

function front_end_post() {

    if( 'POST' == $_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] 
        && !empty( $_POST['action'] ) 
        &&  $_POST['action'] == "new_post") 
    {

    // your logic here

    //your redirect
    $url = get_permalink( $pid );
    wp_redirect($url);
    exit();

    }

}
```

Comment: alright.. after I used your solution, It seems resolved headers problem but still have a problem... it works right way when added image only..